# NodeJs: external javascript with dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, watch, assemble, nodemon

We are trying to use only nodeJS with minimal dependencies to other packages, the challenge we now encounter is HandelbarsJS. We found a package, Assemble who can generate html for us. Only, it is very very slow, about 3 seconds each time, of these 3 seconds, there are  2,5 / 2,7 seconds of the next line:

```
var assemble = require('assemble');
```

Our package.json script section:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:handlebars": "node scripts/handlebars.js",
  "watch:handlebars": "nodemon --watch assets --exec \"npm run build:handlebars\"" }
```

the script/handlebars.js file

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var assemble = require('assemble');
var extname = require('gulp-extname');

console.log(Date.now() - start);

assemble.data('assets/templates/data/*.json');
assemble.layouts('assets/templates/layouts/*.hbs');
assemble.partials('assets/templates/partials/*.hbs');

assemble.src('assets/templates/*.hbs', { layout: 'default' })
    .pipe(extname())
    .pipe(assemble.dest('build/'));
```

Each time, when we save a .hbs file, Nodemon restart and the external javascript file will be called.

How can we ensure that 'require' get called only once, or whether they remain in memory?

Thank you!

Comment: Cant You use a watcher that can inline the assemble code? You need to get rid off the call to the external js file.

Comment: sounds like you want something like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with watch tasks specific for dealing with handlerbars (like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-handlebars) or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-handlebars))

Comment: @Jesse, no, it doesn't have a CLI interface, otherwise, it would be easy. And we want have static HTML as output.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I know Gulp and grunt, but we are looking for a way without those packages. We want to keep the entry threshold fot the company as low as possible.

Comment: Someone else already pointed out chokidar, so that's great, but I need to point out that "keeping the threshold low" is a good argument against gulp (streams are very wtf at first), not so much against grunt (which is mostly normal JS code that anyone can follow if written properly, much like chokidar). That said, also have a look at [`npm scripts`](http://anders.janmyr.com/2014/03/running-scripts-with-npm.html), which are super useful because a lot of build steps can be done with plain CLI utility chaining, so you can take advantage of that *a lot*

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thank you, a nice blog post. at the moment, our build script is set up the same way as you described, but i have left thats steps out of this post, because that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to accomplish using this with `assemble`, but without `gulp`, I recommend `chokidar`.

```
npm install chokidar --save
```

Now you can require `chokidar` like this:

```
var chokidar = require('chokidar');
```

Then define a little helper that runs `handler` whenever something in a pattern changes:

```
function watch(patterns, handler) {
  chokidar.watch(patterns, {
    ignoreInitial: false
  }).on('add', handler).on('change', handler).on('unlink', handler);
}
```

Now we can alter the script like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var assemble = require('assemble');
var extname = require('gulp-extname');
var chokidar = require('chokidar');

console.log(Date.now() - start);

assemble.data('assets/templates/data/*.json');
assemble.layouts('assets/templates/layouts/*.hbs');
assemble.partials('assets/templates/partials/*.hbs');

// Enable --watch command line for Chokidar, otherwise, just run!
if (process.argv.pop() === '--watch') {
  watch('assets', runOnce);
} else {
  runOnce();
}

function watch(patterns, handler) {
  chokidar.watch(patterns, {
    ignoreInitial: false
  }).on('add', handler).on('change', handler).on('unlink', handler);
}

function runOnce() {
  assemble.src('assets/templates/*.hbs', { layout: 'default' })
      .pipe(extname())
      .pipe(assemble.dest('build/'));
}
```

And instead of `nodemon`, this will keep your script alive and running. So, in `npm`, you want this:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:handlebars": "node scripts/handlebars.js",
  "watch:handlebars": "node scripts/handlebars.js --watch"
}
```

Whenever a file changes, the script will now run, without re-invoking from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The beta version of assemble is based on gulp and has a cli that you can use just like you would use gulp, but if you don't want to use the cli and use npm scripts instead,  you can do something based on @roel-van-uden's answer without chokidar and also be able to reload the actual assets (e.g. data, layouts, partials)

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var start = Date.now();
var assemble = require('assemble');
var extname = require('gulp-extname');

assemble.task('assets', function () {
  console.log(Date.now() - start);
  assemble.data('assets/templates/data/*.json');
  assemble.layouts('assets/templates/layouts/*.hbs');
  assemble.partials('assets/templates/partials/*.hbs');

  return assemble.src('assets/templates/*.hbs', { layout: 'default' })
    .pipe(extname())
    .pipe(assemble.dest('build/'));
});

assemble.task('watch', ['assets'], function () {
  assemble.watch('./assets/**/*.*', ['assets]');
});

// Enable --watch command line
if (process.argv.pop() === '--watch') {
  assemble.run(['watch']);
} else {
  assemble.run(['assets']);
}
```

Comment: I will look for it this weekend.

But, every time the command runs, I need to reload the data, layout and partials?